# Scaling a single item in lazy row overlaps the space/padding defined by Arrangement.spacedBy() in LazyRow | Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to achieve consistent spacing among the items but scaling one item overlaps the spacing applied by Arrangement.spacedBy() - which is kinda expected behaviour but is there any way I can achieve consistent spacing?

Appreciate any help. Thank You :)

[image]

Already tried to apply horizontal padding to the item's modifier but it looks choppy when the scroll and scale is performed.